# Can I open .bak file without SQL Server?

Tags: database, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, restore

I want to open an .bak file that was created with SQL Server. There is some method to open that database with any other program?

Thanks.

Comment: "3rd party tool". Plenty of results on search engines. SO isn't really a "recommendation engine".

Comment: What do you mean "open it"?  What, specifically, do you want to do with it?  You can open it in Notepad, but you'll just see a bunch of gobbledygook.  Actually, nevermind.  The question is off-topic anyway, as this is not a programming question, it's a software recommendatin question.

Comment: I want open it to recover few lines from some table

Comment: in `Windows Explorer` right click on `.bak` file. Choose `open with..` option. In the dialog select `Notepad`. click `Ok` :D :D :D

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=3rd+party+tool+open+sql+server+.bak+file&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=3rd+party+tool+open+sql+server+.bak+file&sc=0-0&sp=-1&sk=

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that you are a Windows user, then, you can use Notepad to browse the database if you just need to check some records.